# Pass arguments using hook_menu

Tags: 7, routes

I would build a confirmation screen. So I initialized the path in the `hook_menu` as it should be but for some reason, the argument `$node` isn't send with the function... What am I doing wrong?

This is my `hook_menu`:

```
$items['node/%/revisions/%/offline'] = array(
      'title' => 'Offline,
      'description' => 'Confirm the action "Fiche offline".',
      'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
      'page arguments' => array('_mymodule_confirm_offline'),
      'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
      'weight' => -4,
    ); 
    return $items;
```

And this is my function:

```
function _redactie_omgeving_confirm_offline($form, $form_state, $node) {
    $question = t('Take fiche offline. ');

    return confirm_form($form,
                    $question,
                    'node/7', t('You\'re about to depublish this fiche. <br />Are you sure you want to depublish this fiche?'),
                    t('Yes'), t('Cancel'));
}
```

But the `$node`-variable in my function stays empty... What do I have to do to fill in this variable?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your page callback is `drupal_get_form`, and your page argument is `_mymodule_confirm_offline`, so the call Drupal makes is `drupal_get_form('_mymodule_confirm_offline');`, which doesn't at all seem to be what you want to do.

What you need is a custom callback instead.

In hook_menu:

```
'page callback' => '_confirmation_form_page',
'page arguments' => array(1, 3),
```

And then

```
function _confirmation_form_page($node) {
  $question = t('Take fiche offline. ');

  return confirm_form($form, $question, 'node/' . $node->nid, t('You\'re about to depublish this fiche. <br />Are you sure you want to depublish this fiche?'), t('Yes'), t('Cancel'));
}
```

In order to "auto-load" an object from the url, it needs to be *named*, otherwise Drupal can't know how to perform the load. On a url like "node/%nid", the argument is named "nid". In reality the argument would usually be called %node, but I wanted to distinguish the parts. Drupal will then look for a function called load_nid, pass the number from the URL in, and this function is responsible for returning the fully loaded object. Core has a "load_node" function, so arguments named %node will be auto-loaded without further effort from your part.

To add autoloading into your callback then, you need

`$items['node/%node/revisions/%/offline'] = array(`

However, this will still only give you the right node, not the right revision. [node_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load/7) supports a second argument, `$vid`, that we need to use to get the right revision. Telling Drupal to pass on extra arguments is used with the `load arguments` key, and we need to use the fourth argument from the url `node/%node/revision/%/offline` for this.

So in conclusion, the hook_menu implementation becomes:

```
$items['node/%node/revisions/%/offline'] = array(
  'title' => 'Offline',
  'description' => 'Confirm the action "Fiche offline".',
  'page callback' => '_confirmation_form_page',
  'page arguments' => array(1),
  'load arguments' => array(3),
);
return $items;
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! And what are the 1 and 3 about? Can I add as much items as I want?

Comment: The 1 and 3 correspond to the arguments in 'node/%/revisions/%/offline', with 'node' being 0. This causes the content of the two %'s to be passed in to your callback.

Comment: Ok, great! I'm learning :) How do I get a variable of a previous page in the arguments (let's say `$node`)

Comment: The easiest would be to attach it to the URL, add ?variable=value to the end. I updated my code above a little.

Comment: Ok, great. Thanks. But if I take a look at some contrib/core modules (e.g. Revisioning) I see they are using the same set-up as my initial post and their `$node` gets filled up... So how do they do this?

Comment: By the way, your code just redirects me to my frontpage. I'm not even ending up in my function...

Comment: Second update, added autoloading info.

Comment: Ok, thanks a million for the great update. Is there any chance you can update the code to the 2 updates? So I get a much better understanding?

Comment: Wow, over a year later I accidentally came back. I've updated the code now.

Answer (score 0):

hook_menu does not get $node object as parameter. Node in 'node/%/revisions/%/offline' is just a path it is not any node.